# CloudKit: Query returns partial results, no errors

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckquery, ckmodifyrecordsoperation, ckqueryoperation

I have some kind of CloudKit indexing issue. When I save records to iCloud using CKModifyRecordsOperation, modifyRecordsCompletionBlock returns no errors. When I query those records using NSPredicate(value: true) or Dashboard, most of the time it misses one or two records.

So say I upload 5 records (no errors), wait some time (~15 secs) to make sure that indexes are updated, and then query them (through dashboard or app's CKQueryOperation). Most of the time it will show 4 records out 5. Again, no errors. Records are in privateDB in customZone.

Here is what's strange: I'm **always** able to get records that query didn't return by manually typing recordNames in Dashboard (development) under 'Fetch' menu. So it stores them, just doesn't query. **When I delete indexes** in a dashboard and reassign them, **dashboard query will start to return all the results** (with previously omitted records too),  but after a few more uploads, some will start to be missing from query again.

Here is my CKModifyRecordsOperation:

```
let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: records, recordIDsToDelete: []) 

operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock =
{ [weak self] savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error in

   guard error == nil else { // no errors here ... } 
   ...
   //for each item uploaded to iCloud, mark as synced
   if let savedRecords = savedRecords{ // all attempted to save records are here
        PendingCloudOperations.shared.markAsUploaded(
        savedRecords.map{ $0.recordID.recordName })
   }

   completion(...)
}

operation.savePolicy = .changedKeys          // tried .allKeys too
operation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated  

self.privateDB.add(operation)
```

I experimented with record fields (originally date, asset, and reference) trying to see if any of the fields make a problem. But even if I remove all field's (creating a record with no extra fields, just system meta), problem persists. I didn't include CKQueryOperation code, because Dashboard acts same way as the app.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here are bare-bones of my fetching function:

```
    var receipts:[FS_Receipt] = []

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: myRecordType, predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)

    //completion block
    operation.queryCompletionBlock = { [weak self] cursor, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            // doesn't have any errors here
        }

        completion(...) 
    }

    operation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in

        // doesn't return all records here most of the time.
    }



    operation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated // without this, 'no internet' will NOT return error

    operation.resultsLimit = 5000 

    operation.zoneID = customZoneID


    self.privateDB.add(operation)
}
```

Comment: Show how you return your results and where.

Comment: Michael, does it ever return the correct results? Can you query say the last updated date on all the records only? I don't know how much data your trying to save or indeed how often your running this code; but it sounds like a latency issue of some sort.

Comment: user3069232, yes it returns correct results sometimes. When i remove old indexes and reassign them, for a first few cycles it pushes new records and queries them correctly. After few cycles it stops returning all the records by query. Omitted records can be return only by recordId fetch or by removing indexes and reassigning them again.

Comment: I have the same problem. one time, after CKModifyRecordsOperation about 20 min, I can't query the record. but can  query it by recordName, it's very strange, and after I add a index, it show up.  I test it on dashboard and app. It's all the same.
How do you fix this problem later @MichaelRos